# Lock to Camera to View moves camera position

Tags: camera

Im trying to use Lock Camera to View but when I move the camera while its locked it goes to a completely different place.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). Please add some [screenshots](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) of the issue. Without that it's just guessing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer:) I will do as soon as I can.

Comment: The issue is not present when the camera is not parented to an object - then I can use the Lock Camera to View properly. When the camera is parented, whenever I click on Lock Camera to View and I make the slightest movement, the camera goes to a completely other location. I will post the screenshots soon anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are locking it in the properties tab, you need to lock it with the camera SELECTED, in the camera tab, then you shouldn't have that problem.